# how to have the allure report github pages for each environment?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, allure

Need to have the github pages URL (gh-pages branch) with different environment's allure reports.
The following github workflow steps shows pretty much what I'm trying to do but any help in showing  up the allure report based on environment in the gh-pages would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
      - name: Load Allure History from ${{ env.GH_PAGES_BRANCH }} branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        with:
          ref: ${{ env.GH_PAGES_BRANCH }}
          path: ${{ env.GH_PAGES_BRANCH }}/${{ env.TEST_ENV }}

      - name: Build Allure Report
        uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@v1.7
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        with:
          gh_pages: ${{ env.GH_PAGES_BRANCH }}
          allure_results: allure-results/${{ env.TEST_ENV }}
          allure_report: allure-report/${{ env.TEST_ENV }}
          allure_history: allure-history/${{ env.TEST_ENV }}
          keep_reports: 60

      - name: Publish Allure Report to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_branch: ${{ env.GH_PAGES_BRANCH }}
          publish_dir: allure-history/${{ env.TEST_ENV }}
```